# Gaussian curvature from revolution surface. Where is wrong?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Assume a curve $\gamma(t) = (r(t), 0, h(t))$, and its revolution surface: $X(t, \theta) = (r(t)\cos\theta, r(t)\sin\theta, h(t))$.

After some calculations I find my first and second fundamental form to have expressions [identical to this pdf](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/423-14/surfacesofrevolution.pdf), at page 02, that is:
$$
M_I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad\quad\quad
M_{II} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\ddot r\dot h + \ddot h\dot r & 0 \\
0 & r\dot h \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, it is my understanding that, gaussian curvature calculates:
$$
k = \frac{\det M_{II}}{\det M_I} = 
\frac{r\dot h\left(-\ddot r\dot h + \ddot h\dot r\right)}{r^2\left(\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2\right)\sqrt{\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2}} = 
\frac{\dot h}{r}\frac{-\ddot r\dot h + \ddot h\dot r}{\left(\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$

However, [everywhere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) [seems to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77439/169193) [say](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/423-14/surfacesofrevolution.pdf) that correct result is:
$$
k = \frac{\dot h}{r}\frac{-\ddot r\dot h + \ddot h\dot r}{\left(\dot{r}^2 + \dot{h}^2\right)^2}
$$

I fail to see why is it squared, and not $3/2$ from the determinant calculation. However, after some physical checking, I know the later to be correct. I might be making a tiny arithmetic mistake somewhere, but, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Err... I just found it ~1min after posting. Actually, $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^2\det A$, and not $\lambda\det A$. Silly me. It took me almost an hour in this. =(.

Comment: since you found the mistake, you can convert your comment into an answer and accept it :-)